# why is rails image not resizing using "size =>"?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple static webpage made on rails. Inside the view of the page, I have an embedded ruby code line to display an image called "logos.png". I am trying to display this image stretched horizontally slightly and am trying to do this by increasing the size of the width in pixels, to 2735 x 552 pixels from an original size of 1735 x 552 pixels. Here is my code:

```
<%= image_tag "logos.png", :size => "2735px × 552" %>
```

when I use this code the image remains the same size and does not increase its width. I also tried replacing ":size =>" with "size:". how can I increase the width using this or another method? thank you

Comment: Why would you possibly think that would ever work? You set size of images in HTML by setting the `height` and `width` attributes.

Comment: @max Actually it should work according to the docs https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be in the correct format, according to the docs [`image_tag`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag)
You're using the multiplication symbol for some reason, the method just uses a simple `x` as usual.

> :size - Supplied as “{Width}x{Height}” or “{Number}”, so “30x45”
>   becomes width=“30” and height=“45”, and “50” becomes width=“50” and
>   height=“50”. :size will be ignored if the value is not in the correct
>   format.

```
= image_tag "logos.png", size: "2735x552"
```

Comment: no idea why that symbol is there. i pressed the letter x. there is also another thing i noticed. i left in the "px". thanks.